# Why new date(19, 02) is giving new Date(year, month) 1919-02-28T18:30:00.000Z instead of 1919-03-01T00:00:00.000Z?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

I have node v16.15.1 installed in my PC.
I have ran the same code on online compiler, there getting correct answer
Having some issue with my loacl sysmtem only

Comment: what is this "online compiler" you speak of? javascript isn't compiled

Comment: The value you get is the same as if you used `new Date(19, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)` - which is midnight in your timezone (India by the looks of it) - which is 18:30 the day before in GMT - perhaps the "online compiler" timezone is using GMT